# Trigger Skype for business desktop application from browser

Tags: javascript, skype, skype-for-business

I'm trying to integrate skype for business with my app. I'm trying to get the status of the user on the other end based on sip id , and if the user is online I'm trying to trigger the desktop application from a button click in my web app.

Are the any api calls that enables this action ? Went through the documentation and could not find anything.

Here is what i have so far, this is just the registering part.

```
var skypeWidget = Class.create();
console.log("skype for business js loaded");
var skypeWidgetString = "<div class='sfb_widget'>Skype Widget<a onclick='somefunction()'>Open</a></div>"
jQuery(".requester-details").append(skypeWidgetString);

console.log(Skype);

var config = {
    apiKey: 'apikey', // SDK
    apiKeyCC: 'apikeycc' // SDK+UI
};

var Application;

Skype.initialize({ apiKey: config.apiKey }, function(api) {
    window.skypeWebAppCtor = api.application;
    window.skypeWebApp = new api.application();
    skypeSignIn();
    window.skypeWebApp.signInManager.state.changed(function(state) {
      console.log("in");
    });
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log("cannot load the SDK");
});


var skypeSignIn = function() {
    var client = new Skype.Web.Model.Application;
    client.signInManager.signIn({
        username: "username",
        password: "password"
    }).then(function() {
        alert('Logged in!');
    }, function(error) {
        alert(error);
    });

}

var somefunction(){
  //trigger desktop app here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 'redirecting' to the 'link':

```
window.location = 'skype:some_skype_user?chat';
```

---

To use a variable in place of some_skype_user you need to concatenate it:

```
var skypename = 'skypeuser01';
window.location = 'skype:' + skypename + '?chat';
```